# Count all same column in different condition and get largest one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about how to count all same column in different condition.
For example, I have a set of place which every place contains a time like that

```
+---------+----------------------+
|pTimeslot|pTimeslotPlace        |
|09:30:00 |shifen waterfall park |
|12:30:00 |shifen waterfall park |
|09:30:00 |shifen water fall park|
|09:30:00 |Taipei Ryo Hotel      |
|17:30:00 |Taipei Ryo Hotel      |
|09:30:00 |shifen water fall park|
+---------+----------------------+
```

I want to count all the place in the particular timeslot (morning, afternoon, night something like that), I have tried this code:

```
SELECT pTimeslotPlace, 
SUM(pTimeslot >= '07:00:00' AND pTimeslot <= '11:59:00') Morning, 
SUM(pTimeslot >= '12:00:00' AND pTimeslot <= '16:59:00') Afternoon,
 SUM(pTimeslot >= '17:00:00' AND pTimeslot <= '18:59:00') Evening, 
SUM(pTimeslot >= '19:00:00' AND pTimeslot <= '03:59:00') Night,
 SUM(pTimeslot >= '04:00:00' AND pTimeslot <= '06:59:00') EarlyMorning 
FROM planTime
WHERE pTimeslotPlace = 'shifen waterfall park';
```

The result is this:

```
+---------------------+--------+---------+--------+-------+------------+
|pTimeslotPlace       |Morning |Afternoon|Evening |Night  |EarlyMorning|
|shifen waterfall park|3       |1        |0       |0      |0           |
+---------------------+--------+---------+--------+-------+------------+
```

The question is that:

- How can I get this kind of result in all 'pTimeslotPlace' without
  only one place?
- How can I get the largest number of Morning or Afternoon or Evening or Night or EarlyMorning? In the example, I want to get Morning only as it is the largest one.

Thank you

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select pTimeslotPlace, 
       Case Greatest(Morning, Afternoon, Evening, Night, EarlyMorning)
       WHEN Morning then 'MORNING'
       WHEN Afternoon then 'Afternoon'
       WHEN Evening then 'Evening'
       WHEN Night then 'Night'
       WHEN EarlyMorning THEN 'EarlyMorning'
       END As GreatestTime
From (
SELECT pTimeslotPlace, 
  SUM(pTimeslot >= '07:00:00' AND pTimeslot <= '11:59:00') Morning, 
  SUM(pTimeslot >= '12:00:00' AND pTimeslot <= '16:59:00') Afternoon,
  SUM(pTimeslot >= '17:00:00' AND pTimeslot <= '18:59:00') Evening, 
  SUM(pTimeslot >= '19:00:00' AND pTimeslot <= '03:59:00') Night,
  SUM(pTimeslot >= '04:00:00' AND pTimeslot <= '06:59:00') EarlyMorning 
FROM planTime
group by  pTimeslotPlace )
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, can I change the GreatestTime to a text 'Morning' or 'Afternoon' or 'Evening' something like that, as it only contain a number of GreatestTime only

Comment: OMG, Thank you for your help. it's perfect. I would study this answer

Answer (score 0):

for obtain the valus for all different places you can use group by

```
SELECT pTimeslotPlace, 
  SUM(pTimeslot >= '07:00:00' AND pTimeslot <= '11:59:00') Morning, 
  SUM(pTimeslot >= '12:00:00' AND pTimeslot <= '16:59:00') Afternoon,
  SUM(pTimeslot >= '17:00:00' AND pTimeslot <= '18:59:00') Evening, 
  SUM(pTimeslot >= '19:00:00' AND pTimeslot <= '03:59:00') Night,
  SUM(pTimeslot >= '04:00:00' AND pTimeslot <= '06:59:00') EarlyMorning 
FROM planTime
group by  pTimeslotPlace  ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but how can I only get the largest number? Thank you

Comment: Orderby Descending for largest value

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pTimeslotPlace, 
  SUM(pTimeslot >= '07:00:00' AND pTimeslot <= '11:59:00') Morning, 
  SUM(pTimeslot >= '12:00:00' AND pTimeslot <= '16:59:00') Afternoon,
  SUM(pTimeslot >= '17:00:00' AND pTimeslot <= '18:59:00') Evening, 
  SUM(pTimeslot >= '19:00:00' AND pTimeslot <= '03:59:00') Night,
  SUM(pTimeslot >= '04:00:00' AND pTimeslot <= '06:59:00') EarlyMorning 
FROM Test
group by  pTimeslotPlace order by morning desc;
```

Change morning to any column you want **largest**.

Comment: Sorry for my English, I mean I need to find the largest column in each place

Comment: or it is not possible to do that?

Comment: you can have one largest in a row for place.